# Python teradata Connection exception - UdaExec attribute

Tags: python-3.x, teradata

having a issue connecting to teradata from python

installed teradata module that was missing earlier.

```
import teradata
import pandas as pd
import pyodbc


udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0",logConsole=False)
with udaExec.connect(method="odbc",system="xxxxxx.abc.com", username="xxxxx",password="xxxxxxx", driver="DRIVERNAME") as connect:
        query="SELECT METHOD_NM,EVENT,CHARACTERISTIC from R_VIEWS.EVENT_HIST WHERE EXCEPTION_EVENT_TS  = Date -1 AND exception_nm IN ('ABFSDC');"

        df = pd.read_sql(query,connect)
        print(df.head())



 udaExec = teradata.UdaExec (appName="test", version="1.0", logConsole=False)
```

AttributeError: module 'teradata' has no attribute 'UdaExec'

Comment: What is the name of this script? I've read on other forums that if you are naming this script as `teradata.py` it will conflict with the namespace of the Teradata Python Module and toss an error.

Comment: @JNevill **Extract.py**

Answer (score 0):

As JNevill has said, check if the module name is teradata. It is possible that python is importing your package instead of the teradata package that you've installed.